# Unable to export dataframe as excel file in databricks. If done same with csv file it works

Tags: python, excel, export

I am using the code below to export a dataframe in excel format from databricks which returns the following error:
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: dbfs:/df_xl.xlsx"

```
 path= 'abfss://raw@tkm.dfs.core.windows.net/db_folder/'

 df1.to_excel('df_xl.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
 dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/df_xl.xlsx', path + 'output')
```

If i do the same thing with csv it is working perfectly.

Can you please help me with thi?

Comment: what error r u getting

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /df_xl.xlsx